# Codeigniter: Join 3 tables and display data in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have 3 tables I wish to join.

I am building an app i Codeigniter and I have 3 tables

**Client:**
-id
-phone_number
-hospital_id
-smc_status
-testing_center_id

**Hospital**
-id
-name

**Testing_center**
-id
-name

In the model,I have this:

```
public function get_clients()
    {
        if($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $this->db->select('clients.*');
            $this->db->from('clients');
            $this->db->join('hospital', 'clients.id = hospital.id');
            $this->db->join('testing_center', 'clients.id = testing_center.id');
            $query = $this->db->get();

            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('clients');
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

In the view I have:

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($clients as $client_item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $client_item['phone_number'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $client_item['smc_status'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $client_item['hospital_id'] ?></td> //i wish to have the hospital name here
        <td><?php echo $client_item['testing_center_id'] ?></td> //i wish to have the testing center name here
        <td><?php echo $client_item['language'] ?></td>
        <td><a href="#">View</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

But that is because I have failed to show the hospital name and the testing center name on the third and fourth td. How can I go about that? I tried a few techniques that just did not seem to work for some reason. Please advise

Answer (score 3):

You're only selecting the values from the `clients` table. You need to select the columns from the other tables as well

```
$this->db->select('clients.id, 
    clients.phone_number,
    clients.smc_status,
    clients.language,
    hospital.name AS hospital_name, 
    testing_center.name AS testing_center_name');
```

Then you can access them by

```
<?php echo $client_item['hospital_name'] ?>
<?php echo $client_item['testing_center_name'] ?>
```

EDIT: Also you [shouldn't use SELECT *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select), which `clients.*` is doing. Updated my code.

Comment: I have made the changes but I end up getting the HTTP Error 500. Why is that?

Comment: There are a number of different things that could have went wrong. Check your PHP log.

Comment: I am running it on my localhost and I cannot check any logs, but I simply changed to: 
 $this->db->select('clients.id,
clients.phone_number,
clients.smc_status,
clients.language,
hospital.name AS hospital_name,    testing_center.name AS testing_center_name');
$this->db->from('clients');
$this->db->join('hospital', 'hospital.id = clients.id');
$this->db->join('testing_center', 'testing_center.id = clients.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
$query = $this->db->get_where('clients', array('slug' => $slug));
return $query->row_array();
}
}

Comment: I think I had mis-spelled something. It works perfectly now. Thanks so much!

Comment: I am trying to fill a form and push data back to the database into the different tables. How would I go about that? DO i first bind the form to the database such that it understands the joins or should i place input text similar to what is expected in the database?

Comment: Just to add to this solution - you can use the select multiple times. You can do:
$this->db->select('clients.*');
$this->db->select('hospital.name as hospital_name');
$this->db->select('testing_center.id as testing_center_id');

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try this:

```
 $this->db->join('hospital', 'hospital.id = clients.id');
 $this->db->join('testing_center', 'testing_center.id = clients.id');
```

instead of this:

```
 $this->db->join('hospital', 'clients.id = hospital.id');
 $this->db->join('testing_center', 'clients.id = testing_center.id');
```

also check

client**s** and client if they are the same everywhere

And also change as Nerd proposed:
$this->db->select('clients.*'); 
to:

```
$this->db->select('*');
```

Comment: I have made all the necessary changes first the recommendations by Nerd, as well as yours but I end up getting the HTTP Error 500. Why is that?

Comment: Checked and I had made some spelling errors. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I am trying to fill a form and push data back to the database into the different tables. How would I go about that? DO i first bind the form to the database such that it understands the joins or should i place input text similar to what is expected in the database?

Answer (score 0):

It sholud be like this

```
 $this->db->join('hospital', 'clients.hospital_id = hospital.id');
 $this->db->join('testing_center', 'clients.testing_center_id  = testing_center.id');
```

Comment: There is an wrong with the joining the same column names in both tabls like ("hospital_id in clients,id in hospital") and ("testing_center_id in clients,id in testing_center")